# Convert Int Array to Blob

Tags: array, blob

I have an Integer array using it as a ByteArray (It is a publicKey)
[-33,103,-48,-46,113 .......]

How can I convert it to Blob using Apex?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read about [ask] and take our quick [tour]. "I hope you are doing well" and "Thank you so much" are not needed in your questions here. Just state plainly what you're trying to do and include as much information as possible. This question may be an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/); you might want to [edit] it to be more specific about what you're doing, what you've tried so far, etc.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks for sharing, I'll take the quick tour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apex doesn't have the notion of "byte arrays", unfortunately, so there's no one-liner that can do this. The best you can do if you start from this array would be something like:

```
Integer[] values = new Integer[]{-33, 103, -48, -46, 113, ...};
// Buffer
String[] hexValues = new String[0];
// Hex lookup
String[] hex = '0123456789abcdef'.split('');
for(Integer byteValue: values) {
    // Isolate bits 4-7: (240) 0xF0 is the mask
    // Divide by 16 (shift right 4 bits)
    Integer highNybble = (byteValue & 240) >> 4;
    // Isolate bits 0-3 (15) 0x0F is the mask
    Integer lowNybble = byteValue & 15;
    // Write high and low 
    hexValues.add(hex[highNybble]);
    hexValues.add(hex[lowNybble]);
}
Blob result = EncodingUtil.convertFromHex(String.join(hexValues,''));
System.debug(result);
```

Not terrible, but if you can just take the key's hex output, you get a much more legible:

```
String publicKeyHex = 'df67d0d271...';
Blob publicKey = EncodingUtil.convertFromHex(publicKeyHex);
```

Comment: It works perfectly, I see, so hex values are easily converted to Blobs, I'll keep that in mind, Thank you @sfdcfox !